# asp mvc route behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I got a problem with routin in my asp mvc application: `The resource cannot be found.`

`Requested URL: /Admin/Users/Update`

My action code is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int userId)
{
    -some code-
    return View();
}
```

ActionLink is:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)fullName, "Update", "Users", new { userId = user.Id }, null)
```

Route:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/",
        new { controller = "Units", action = "Units" },
        new [] {"RSystem.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
     );
 }
```

But others actions, for example

```
public ActionResult Users(Role? role)
```

work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your ActionLink to match the action name:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)fullName, "UpdateUser", "Users", new { userId = user.Id }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install T4MVC from nuget and avoid these mistakes, you will have controllers and actions in your intellisence!
I know it is a headache to hard code controller and action names.

Your code with t4mvc:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)fullName, MVC.Users.UpdateUser(), new { userId = user.Id }, null);
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As your ActionResult method name is UpdateUser so in ActionLink you have to pass like this

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)fullName, "UpdateUser", "Users", new { userId = user.Id }, null)
```